# How to check what button is clicked in this case

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML (Generated dynamically)

```
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup t1">Save changes</button>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup t2">Save changes</button>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup t3">Save changes</button>

$(document).on("click", ".savepopup", function (e)
{
var tvalue= $(this).attr('class');    

});
```

I need to put a condition in my javascript as

```
if(tvalue=='t1')
{
}

else if(tvalue=='t2')
{
}

else if(tvalue=='t3')
{
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vz58n67r/

Could anybody please help me .

Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(document).on("click", ".savepopup", function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass("t1")){

    } else if($(this).hasClass("t2")) {

    } else if($(this).hasClass("t3")) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much , whats the reason for using e.preventDefault(); in this case ??

Comment: @PreethiJain Ah thats my bad, I thought I saw anchor tags instead of button tags. `e.preventDefault();` can be ommited in this case.

Comment: @PreethiJain Why to call a function multiple times when you can call  `match` single time using the value then?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `hasClass` function, but for performance, don't use it.

Use a regular expression to match the tvalue: `/(t[0-9]+)$/`:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".savepopup", function (e) {
    var tvalue= $(this).attr('class').match(/(t[0-9]+)$/)[1];
    switch(tvalue) {
       case "t1":
           alert(1);
           /* do something when t1 is clicked */
           break;
       case "t2":
           alert(2);
           /* do something when t2 is clicked */
           break;
       case "t3":
           alert(3);
           /* do something when t3 is clicked */
           break;
       default:
           alert(tvalue);
           /* do something for other t values*/
           break;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup t1">Save changes t1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup t2">Save changes t2</button>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup t3">Save changes t3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup t4">Save changes t4</button>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup t5">Save changes t5</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Via jQuery you can check the class with:

```
if($(this).hasClass('t1')){
  //do somthing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [.hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) enables you to check whether a class attribute is set for the current element.

```
$(document).on("click", ".savepopup", function (e)
{
    if($(this).hasClass("t1"))
    {
    }
    if($(this).hasClass("t2"))
    {
    }
    if($(this).hasClass("t3"))
    {
    }
});
```

Using `else if` and `else` is also doable if you're 100% certain that the class properties will always be unique.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vz58n67r/4/).

Using [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) is also one way to do it but it's a bad solution since it forbids you to change your class structure.

```
var tvalue = $(this).attr('class').split("btn blue savepopup ")[1];
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vz58n67r/6/).

Comment: Nice solution , but my css person will not accept this .

Comment: @PreethiJain Can you be more precise? The link to the demos should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using class, I would recommend using a `data-*` attribute

```js
$(document).on("click", ".savepopup", function(e) {
  var tvalue = $(this).data('type');
  alert(tvalue)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup" data-type="t1">Save changes</button>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup" data-type="t2">Save changes</button>
<button type="button" class="btn blue savepopup" data-type="t3">Save changes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".savepopup", function (e) {
    var tvalue= $(this);   
    if(tvalue.hasClass('t1')) {
        console.log("t1");
    }
    else if(tvalue.hasClass('t2')) {
        console.log("t2");
    }
    else if(tvalue.hasClass('t3')) {
        console.log("t3");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using the best method here, could you not use radio buttons instead?

```
<form id ='fred' action="">
<input type="radio" name="blue savepopup" value="t1">t1<br>
<input type="radio" name="blue savepopup" value="t2">t1
</form>
```

then in javascript you could use

```
function getCheckedRadio(group) {
for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    var button = group[i];
    if (button.checked) {
        return button;
    }
}
return undefined;
}
```